# EAP-FAST session ID format in RFC is not matching packet capture

Tags: tls

RFC 4851 for EAP-FAST says the following:

3.5.  EAP-FAST Session Identifier

The EAP session identifier is constructed using the random values
provided by the peer and server during the TLS tunnel establishment.
The Session-Id is defined as follows:

```
  Session-Id  = 0x2B || client_random || server_random)
 client_random = 32 byte nonce generated by the peer
 server_random = 32 byte nonce generated by the server
```

But in my pcap, it does not start 0x2B and has only 32-byte. What do I miss?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The value you're showing is the TLS session ID from the Server Hello message of the TLS handshake. It's not the EAP session ID.

For the EAP session ID, you have to look at the [`EAP-Key-Name` attribute of the RADIUS/Diameter protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5247.html#section-5.9). As far as I understand, this attribute should be in the `Access-Accept` packet that the access point receives from the RADIUS server.